# What powder is used for explosions in movies?

Tags: effects

When there are explosions in movies they use a powder, but what is the name of the powder that is used for the explosions? What is the chemical name?

Comment: Are you asking about *explosive* powder? Blasting powder used to be the case, now it's much more controlled with proper plastic explosive I would assume.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106956/how-do-movies-make-explosions?rq=1

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqJiWbD08Yw

Comment: I would think it would depend on the type and scale and desired "look" of the explosion...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do movies make explosions?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106956/how-do-movies-make-explosions)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, explosions are just created with CGI in post-production. However, in the few cases where real explosions *are* created, it usually depends on the type of explosion required.

Petrol and Propane are highly flammable liquids that can combust from a spark so it is often used practically to create an explosion purely for effect. [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqJiWbD08Yw) [[2]](https://www.insider.com/how-explosions-are-made-for-movies-and-tv-2020)

As a case study later used for creating the explosion of the Death Star, a mixture of sulfur, potassium nitrate and charcoal was ignited on a minature which produced *sparks and debris which were propelled towards the camera as if travelling outward in the vacuum of space*. The resulting blast was later reproduced using special effects for Star Wars: A New Hope (Episode IV).  [[3]](https://www.acs.org/content/dam/acsorg/education/resources/highschool/chemmatters/articlesbytopic/thermochemistry/chemmatters-dec2009-hollywood.pdf)